# Sorting Search Results by attribute that is not available (isn't listed in dropdown)

Tags: sorting

Just like my topic says: Is it possible to set default sorting order (eg. by setDefaultOrder() function) to attribute that is not available - isn't listed in "sort by" dropdown list?

What I want to achieve is to search results are default sorted by "my_attribute", but "my_attribute" isn't possible to choose from "sort by" select.

I hope that this is clear enough :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your attribute options set `Used for Sorting in Product Listing` to `yes` and then your attribute will show up in sort option

hope that helps

Comment: No. It doesn't help. This option is reserved for product listing only (I think..).

Comment: my attributes set this way are available in search product listing sort options